# ASP.NET MVC Returning Partial View as a full View Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderpartial

I have a number of partial views that are used to render media in different formats (embedded video mainly). I now have a requirement that has me displaying these videos inside an iframe. Is there a way that I can return a minimal HTML page with the partial views embedded in it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out these discussion about how to render a partial view to string.

[RenderPartial to String in ASP.NET MVC Beta](http://www.brightmix.com/blog/how-to-renderpartial-to-string-in-asp-net-mvc/)

[RenderPartial to string](http://forums.asp.net/t/1315284.aspx)