# Load all partials in a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have this:

```
Views/MyView/_partials
   ... partial1.cshtml
   ... partial2.cshtml
   ... partial3.cshtml
```

And I'm loading them like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_partials/partial1.cshtml")
    @Html.Partial("_partials/partial2.cshtml")
    @Html.Partial("_partials/partial3.cshtml")
</div>
```

Is there a way to load all files in that directory?

Comment: Do they need to be separate Partial Views? Why not combine them.

Comment: Yes, because is easier to maintain my code.

Comment: Understandable, have a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348163/asp-net-mvc-loading-multiple-partial-views-into-a-single-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string virtual_path = Server.MapPath("~/Views/MyView/_partials");   

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(virtual_path); 
FileInfo[] filesInDir = directory.GetFiles("*.cshtml"); 
List<string> list = new List<string>(); 

foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir) 
{ 
    list.Add(Path.Combine(foundFile.Directory.Name, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(foundFile.Name))); 
}
```

You can get the files like this and pass it to the ViewBag so you can use in your view

```
@foreach (string file in ViewBag.OptionsFiles) 
{ 
  @Html.Partial(file) 
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was fast. I'm going to try that. Thanks